# UICollectionView didSelecteItem Delegate behaving weirdly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewdelegate

I have a `UICollectionView` to show some components.
Its vertical scrolling and with only 1 column.

I am adding 2 same objects but with different data to `collectionView`'s datasource at different sections.

And in my `cell` class my initialisation and update methods are as follow

```
- (void)commonInitializer {

    self.backgroundColor = kVTColorWhite;

    self.imageView = [[VTUIKit imageSquareXL2] addToSuperview:self];
    self.imageView.f_x = kVTPadding;
    self.imageView.backgroundColor = kVTColorBackground;
    self.imageView.f_width = [VTAdSpaceDisplayCell cellSize].width - 2*kVTPadding;
    self.imageView.f_height = [VTUIKit screenWidth]/3.125;
    self.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 2.0;
    self.imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
}


- (void)updateWithModel:(id)model{

    self.model = model;

    if (self.model.image == nil) {
        [self updateEmptyCells];
    }
    else{
        [self.imageView setImageWithUrl:self.model.image optimizedForSize:[self class] cellSize] withPlaceholder:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Placeholder-Image"]];
    }
}
```

But `collectionView`'s `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` for this cell is being called sometimes and sometimes not, its very weird.

I have also set `collectionView`'s delegate to current class and I am also not adding any `gesture recogniser` to cell or `collectionView`.

But still the behaviour is strange and very random, I cant even get a particular scenario to debug.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Your issue can be in many different places, can you show more code from the collection view ? like how and when you reload data and how you init those items.

Comment: does adding this to your imageView make any difference: self.imageView.userInteractionEnabled = true;

Comment: Actually the problem is weird and I cant find the reason for this issue to occur, I'll post it as answer here. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual problem is nowhere related to `UIImageView` or `UICollectionViewCell`.

Earlier I was using `[self.collectionView reloadSections:[INDEX]]` for reloading `collectionView`'s sections and that was creating some problems and I dont know why.

But, I changed them to `[self.collectionView reloadData]` and the issue is gone.

Very strange and weird reason for issue to appear and I have no explanation even though I searched for it.

Anyways, I got my issue resolved so I am posting my solution as an answer if that helps anyone in future.

Thanks